# processing/Java: two outputs from one arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, output, processing

I would like to have two outputs, for as if i type in "ora", i would like it to output "orange" and "orange juice", in two strings, but how would you do?

```
class searcher {
      ArrayList<String> toBecompared= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("orange", "orange juice", "apples", "cola", "soda"));
      void search() {
        String[] words = {text}; 
        // text is a user input
        // for loop test for if the "list" contains "text" (user input)
        for (int i = 0; i < toBecompared.size(); i++) {
          for (int w = 0; w < text.length(); w++) {
            try { 
              if (toBecompared.get(i).contains(words[w])) {
                println(words[w] +"  " + toBecompared.get(i));
              }
            }
            catch(Exception a) {
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

i found a way to do it, but im not sure if it is the best way :P

```
class searcher {
  ArrayList<String> toBecompared= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("orange", "orange_juice", "apples", "cola", "soda"));
  String comparing ="orange orange_juice apples cola soda";
  String[] splited = comparing.split("\\s+");
  String compared1;
  String compared2;

  boolean True = false;

  void search() {
    String[] words = {text}; // text is a user input
    for (int i = 0; i < toBecompared.size(); i++) {
      for (int w = 0; w < text.length(); w++) {
        try { 
          if (toBecompared.get(i).contains(words[w])) {
            //println(words[w] +"  " + toBecompared.get(i));

            if (True == true) {
              compared2 = splited[i];
              True = false;
            } else {
              compared1 = splited[i];
              True = true;
            }
          }
          println(compared1);
          println(" ");
          println(compared2);
        }

        catch(Exception a) {
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest making a `List<String>`, loop over your inputs, if it matches then add it to the list.  At the end of the loop, you can do what you want with the list.  If you only want 2 things, only print the first two (check you have at least 2, of course).  Also,  `boolean True = false;` makes my brain hurt :-)

Comment: @Lampen it feels like your trying to implement an auto-complete like functionality. If so, you should look into [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: For the love of Reas don't ever use an empty exception block. At least put a call to `a.printStackTrace()` in there.

Comment: @George Profenza , yes thats what im trying to do thank you very much :D

Comment: @Kevin Workman im a pretty new to programing, so thank you very much, i didnt know about that command :)

Comment: @Lampen No problem. Empty catch blocks are evil just because it'll hide any errors from you. So you should always put something in there, just so you know if something goes wrong.

Comment: @Stik i know, i should had changed it, but i forget before i uploadede it here (i have changed it in my code) ( i was just trying some different stuff, so names didnt matter, at the time)